# jquery + fancybox issue, fancybox jquery event does not "see" html content which was just added to DOM tree

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, fancybox, dynamic-data

I am using jQuery with [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto) for generating images gallery this way: I show to user just one medium-sized image which he clicks (and after that click other images links being preloaded into hidden `<div>`) and gets nice images gallery.

*I need to preload image links because it's not a static list, it depends on first image which user clicked and this way I can prevent fancybox to show duplicate images.*

Here is my code (a bit messy, because I'm getting image urls from ruby):

## javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $('#car_image').click(function(e) { // generating fancybox gallery containing only large images
    // here we should generate fancybox <div id="large_images_gallery_div"> and place this div inside of <div id="car_image">

    var gallery_images_urls = [];
    var gallery_images_tagged = '';

    <% @car.photos.each do |car_photo| %>
        var current_image_url = '<%= car_photo.image.url(:large) %>';

        if(current_image_url != $('#changeme').attr('href')) gallery_images_tagged += '<a href="' + current_image_url + '" class="fancybox" rel="my_car_gallery" />';
    <% end%>

        $('#car_image div#large_images_gallery_div').replaceWith('<div id="large_images_gallery_div" style="visibility: hidden;">' + gallery_images_tagged + '</div');

    });

  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();


});
```

## html:

```
<div id="car_image">
    <%= link_to @car.photos.first.image.url(:large), :class => "fancybox", :rel => "my_car_gallery", :id => "changeme" do %>
        <%= image_tag @car.photos.first.image.url(:medium) %>
    <% end%>

    <div id="large_images_gallery_div" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <-- HERE ALL GALLERY IMAGES LINKS BEING PRELOADED -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**THE ISSUE**: my list being loaded correctly, but fancybox shows me just first image and does not show others, which was added by jQuery's `replaceWith()` method

possible it can't "see" that DOM tree has been changed

BTW, sorry for my poor english

***UPDATE***

## html before images links preloading:

```
<div id="car_image">
    <a rel="my_car_gallery" id="changeme" class="fancybox" href="/uploads/photo/image/44/large_1.jpg">
        <img src="/uploads/photo/image/44/medium_1.jpg">
    </a>

    <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="large_images_gallery_div">

    </div>
</div>
```

## html after images links preloading:

```
<div id="car_image">
    <a rel="my_car_gallery" id="changeme" class="fancybox" href="/uploads/photo/image/44/large_1.jpg">
        <img src="/uploads/photo/image/44/medium_1.jpg" >
    </a>

    <div style="visibility: hidden;" id="large_images_gallery_div">
        <a rel="my_car_gallery" class="fancybox" href="/uploads/photo/image/45/large_2.jpg"></a>
        <a rel="my_car_gallery" class="fancybox" href="/uploads/photo/image/46/large_3.jpg"></a>
        <a rel="my_car_gallery" class="fancybox" href="/uploads/photo/image/47/large_4.jpg"></a>
        <a rel="my_car_gallery" class="fancybox" href="/uploads/photo/image/48/large_5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was told on `#jquery @ freenode` this question is about [jQuery.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) so I got help with this method:

```
$('#car_image').delegate(
    ".fancybox",
    "click",
        function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox(
                (function () {
                    var gallery_images_urls = [];

                    gallery_images_urls.push('<img src="' + $('a#changeme').attr('href') + '" />'); // pushing first image

                    <% @car.photos.each do |car_photo| %>
                        if($('a#changeme').attr('href') != '<%= car_photo.image.url(:large) %>') gallery_images_urls.push('<img src="<%= car_photo.image.url(:large) %>" />');
                    <% end %>

                    return gallery_images_urls;
                }).bind(this)(),
                    {
                        transitionIn : 'elastic',
                        transitionOut : 'elastic',
                        speedIn : 600,
                        speedOut : 200
                    }
            );
    }
);
```

which triggers `delegate()` for every click on `#car_image`, I solved to provide fancybox images objects directly to `$.fancybox()` method without any additional html preloading